# Can a record be in multiple "realms" in Dexie?

Tags: dexie

[In this example](https://dexie.org/cloud/docs/access-control#example-sharable-todo-list), we see updating a record with a key `realmId`

```js
// Move todo-list into the realm (if not already there):
db.todoLists.update(todoList.id, { realmId });
```

Is it possible for a record to be in multiple "realms"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, a record can only belong to a single realm in Dexie Cloud. But a realm can be shared to many people by adding several "members" that connects the realm to users.